# What is the tool for GNU/Linux to edit order of directory entries on FAT filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32

It is needed because of my portable audio player does not order entries and just leaves it as in FAT directory.

Current way of handling this is only moving files around and re-creating directories and placing files there in correct order (keeping in mind where are "holes" in directory list that will be filled by new file in placed to that directory).

What is the more proper way of doing it? (Apart from re-creating all directories each time or using hex editor on disk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a program called fatsort.  A current link is here: http://fatsort.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "It was developed because I wanted to sort my MP3 files on my MP3 hardware player." -> Looks like such players are not rare.